# Copying certain levels from an unordered list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom-manipulation

I'm a beginner programmer and I'm stuck with the following problem:
If I have a nested unordered list, how can I copy only the elements up
to a certain level? For example if I want to reduce this unordered list to the first two levels:

```
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <ul>
    <li>C<br>
    </li>
    <li>D<br>
    </li>
    <ul>
      <li>E<br>
      </li>
      <li>F<br>
      </li>
      <ul>
        <li>G<br>
        </li>
        <li>H<br>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
    <li>E<br>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <li>B</li>
</ul>
```

to

```
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <ul>
    <li>C<br>
    </li>
    <li>D<br>
    </li>
    <li>E<br>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <li>B</li>
</ul>
```

Is there any easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple version:

```
$('ul ul ul').remove();
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VKr38/1/)

I also wrote a little function that lets you specify a root element and a level also:

```
function reduce(root, selector, level) {
    var use = root;
    for (var i = 0; i <= level; i++) {
        use += ' ' + selector;
    }
    $(use).remove();
}
```

Use by calling:

```
//if the lists are in an element with the id 'root', see Demo
reduce('#root', 'ul', 2);
```

​
[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VKr38/3/)

Answer (score 1):

This should be something like `$('ul ul ul').remove()`, but you'd better enclose it in for example div with id or class so you can do local purge `$('div.twolvls ul ul ul').remove()`

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply removing 3rd level unordered lists, you could use `$(ul ul ul).remove()`.

Comment: You forgot the quotes `$('ul...`